# How to send sms in proper format using php?

Tags: php, html, css, mobile, sms

In this code I have am using sms gateway to send message to client. Now, sms sent successfully but format look plain like:

`This is a remainder about the title by the 2019-11-11 hello`

it look simple I want to show message should be like:

`This is a remainder about`
`the title`
`by 2019-11-11`
`hello`
Line should be break after `about`, `title`, `date` and `message`

So How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

```
$message = "This is a reminder about the ".$this->input->post("title")." by the ".date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->input->post("date")))." ".strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->input->post("notice")))."";
$requestParams = array(
    'user' => '**********',
    'pass' => '**********',
    'sender' => '*******',
    'phone' => trim(json_encode($student_phone, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK),'[]'),
    'text' => $message,
    'priority' => 'ndnd',
    'stype' => 'normal'
);
$apiUrl = "http://bhashsms.com/api/sendmsg.php?";
foreach($requestParams as $key => $val){
    $apiUrl .= $key.'='.urlencode($val).'&';
}

$apiUrl = rtrim($apiUrl, "&");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$return = json_encode($result);
```

Comment: It's unclear, at least for me, how is the format you want different from the one that's working right now. All I see is that the preposition "the" is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with "new line" character `\n`. Insert it in the string like this:

```
$message = "This is a reminder about \n the ".$this->input->post("title")."\n by the ".date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->input->post("date")))."\n".strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->input->post("notice")))."";
```